# Question about USPTO Forms

Tags: forms

I've got a really basic question.  On most, if not all fillable forms for the USTPO, there is a field that reads

> Total of ____ forms are submitted.

What should I be entering here?

Comment: My guess would be the number of forms submitted in one mail/submission. Or am I missing something here? (Haven't done it and don't know the answer, just curious if there is something more in the context or it's really that simple)

Answer (score 1):

It explains at the bottom of the form. (see example)

> NOTE: This form must be signed in accordance with 37 CFR 1.33. See 37 CFR 1.4 for signature requirements and certifications. Submit multiple forms if more than one signature is required, see below*

This is for the the USPTO to make sure that it has as many forms as were intended to be sent such as in facsimile (fax) transmission of documents. If the connection interrupts, the USPTO may not receive all of the forms needed to proceed. Putting the number of forms at the bottom allows them to verify that nothing has been left off or that forms are mixed with another stack of forms.

Additionally you would also include a [certificate of mailing](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/sb0092.pdf).

Example: [REQUEST FOR ORAL HEARING BEFORE
THE PATENT TRIAL AND APPEAL BOARD](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/aia0032.pdf)